# permission of start capturing everything that display in my screen in android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

I can capture everything on my screen using android MediaProjection api along with MediaRecorder API. When i try to capture for the first time it prompt for permission automatically. I want to take permission manually for Marshmallow. How can i take permission manually ? is it possible?

The link below say that it prompt for permission on createScreenCaptureIntent() method call. I have implemented on my way but need to take permission explicitly before starting my need.

https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/screenshots-and-screen-recordings

Answer (score 0):

While we call

```
startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SCREEN_RECORDING);
```

it transfer call to

```
onActivityResult(Intent intent, int requestcode, int resultcode)
```

if `resultcode` is OK and `MediaRecorder`, `mediaProjecttionManager` and `VirtualDisplay` are not null, thhen we can say that we get capturing screen permission otherwise the value of `mediaPorjection` and `VirtualDisplay` will be null